# Mapbox GL js touchend geo-coordinate not coverting to number in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to display a marker in mapbox GL js when the user touch the screen and the marker display on that coordinate. The marker.setLngLat() method takes a array of coordinate in a number format which i have passed but in console log it give error of NaN.

Here are my codes,

```
updatelocation(){
    this.map.on('touchend',function(e) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(e.lngLat));
      this.longitude = parseFloat(e.lngLat.lng);
      this.latitude = parseFloat(e.lngLat.lat);

    });

    this.marker.setLngLat([this.longitude,this.latitude]).addTo(this.map);

  }
```

And here is the error
[image]

Can someone help me, i am really stuck.

Comment: I think you need to move your `this.marker.setLngLat...` line inside the `touchend` event listener.

Comment: @mollymerp If i move setLngLat inside touchend eventlistener. it will give me ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'setLngLat' of undefined. I have declare this.marker = new mapboxgl.Marker(); in the constructor and took its object reference but it is returning undefined.

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle or jsbin of what you're seeing?